# How to show log on Spring Cloud Data Flow UI

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have tried to view log of task on Spring Cloud Data Flow UI. However I got the message that: **Log could not be retrieved as the task instance is not running** when I used the REST ENDPOINT : localhost:9393/dashboard/#tasks/executions/33

When I launch my task for the first time with task id is 33, the log is showed on UI. But when I relaunch the same task again (task id is 34), the log of id 34 is showed but the log of id 33 is gone.

Im using SCDF version 2.2.2 and spring-cloud-deployer-local version 2.0.6. 
How to keep log of all task id on the UI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Spring Cloud Data Flow server uses `local` deployer to handle the task lifecycle management(launch, stop, etc.,), the corresponding task execution log can be obtained **only** when the task execution status is `RUNNING`.

This is by design because the `local` task launcher prunes the task instance history every time a new task instance is launched and hence the access to the log is not available. If you want to explore the code, you can check it [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/blob/dff003337b2e26a7b1d6004f6692823399ad0289/spring-cloud-deployer-local/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/local/LocalTaskLauncher.java#L132) which is based on [this Github issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/issues/112)

Comment: mean that they just keep the task instance history when deploying on cloud framework? so are there anyway to keep the task instance history for local?

Comment: but why we need to pruneTaskInstanceHistory on local ?